# Android ZXing Barcode Scanner displays the wrong result

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I am designing an app for scan Barcode. There are three activities where I have used Barcode Scanner, only in one Activity the code is working fine and other two activities its taking too much time to scan and some times scans but displaying wrong result.

I am very confused about what the problem is. Same code I have copy paste in all three activities.

build.gradle:

`compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'`

Code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScanBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

     private ZXingScannerView scannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

                if(scannerView== null)
                {
                    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);
                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result result) {
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(ScanBoxActivity.this,""+scanResult,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                onResume();
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compile 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

This library has google support and easy to implement and I have implemented it in one of my app. So, if you face any further issue , ask me freely.

Comment: How to decrease the Screen Size and how to implement Continuous Scanning. I am showing result on Dialog there are two buttons in dialog one for go next Activity and one for again Scan, How to do Again Scan when click on dialog button. @Ayush

Answer (score 0):

DO you have samples of the code you used AYUSH ARYA to share or maybe an e m a i l?

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the question. This is not an answer. I understand you don't have enough reputation for that but you have to gain some more reputation first.

Comment: You can get Source code by this 

URL : https://github.com/EdwardvanRaak/MaterialBarcodeScanner

Comment: so Roel , I want to follow the rules as SO is the very definition of Awesome.  Is there any way to add comments.  My level of knowledge is not very high to answer many questions to gain rep.  Any suggestions?